# R split hierarchical list of lists

Tags: r, list

I have a list of lists. I want to split this list into two list.
It is better to explain in example. So here is example.

List consist of 3 lists.
Each of the list element is a list of 2 data.frames. (person, car)

```
df1 = data.frame(id = 1, name = "John")
df2 = data.frame(id = 1, car = "Opel")

list1 = list(person = df1, car = df2)
list2 = list(person = df1, car = df2)
list3 = list(person = df1, car = df2)

listMain = list(list1,list2,list3)
```

The output of `str(listMain)`:

```
List of 3
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ person:'data.frame':  1 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ id  : num 1
  .. ..$ name: Factor w/ 1 level "John": 1
  ..$ car   :'data.frame':  1 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ id : num 1
  .. ..$ car: Factor w/ 1 level "Opel": 1
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ person:'data.frame':  1 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ id  : num 1
  .. ..$ name: Factor w/ 1 level "John": 1
  ..$ car   :'data.frame':  1 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ id : num 1
  .. ..$ car: Factor w/ 1 level "Opel": 1
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ person:'data.frame':  1 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ id  : num 1
  .. ..$ name: Factor w/ 1 level "John": 1
  ..$ car   :'data.frame':  1 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ id : num 1
  .. ..$ car: Factor w/ 1 level "Opel": 1
```

I want to split this list into two lists.
First one should be personList, second is carList. Like this.

```
> listPerson <- list(df1,df2,df3)
> str(listPerson)
List of 3
 $ :'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ id  : num 1
  ..$ name: Factor w/ 1 level "John": 1
 $ :'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ id  : num 1
  ..$ name: Factor w/ 1 level "John": 1
 $ :'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ id  : num 1
  ..$ name: Factor w/ 1 level "John": 1
> listCars <- list(df4,df5,df6)
> str(listCars)
List of 3
 $ :'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ id : num 1
  ..$ car: Factor w/ 1 level "Opel": 1
 $ :'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ id : num 1
  ..$ car: Factor w/ 1 level "Opel": 1
 $ :'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ id : num 1
  ..$ car: Factor w/ 1 level "Opel": 1
```

How to do that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `lapply` to go through each element in `listMain` and extract the first (second) element. I think the key point here is the use of `[[` like any "traditional" function in `lapply`.

```
listPerson <- lapply(listMain, `[[`, 1)
listCar <- lapply(listMain, `[[`, 2)
```

As @Frank suggests in the comment, you can subset by name as well. The key point remains that you can use `[[` like regular function.

```
listPerson <- lapply(listMain, `[[`, "person")
```

To read the docs for this function, type `` ?`[[` ``.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `purrr::transpose` to flip the list from 3 elements containing 2 each to 2 containing 3 each:

```
library(purrr)

tListMain <- transpose(listMain)

str(tListMain)

## List of 2
##  $ person:List of 3
##   ..$ :'data.frame': 1 obs. of  2 variables:
##   .. ..$ id  : num 1
##   .. ..$ name: Factor w/ 1 level "John": 1
##   ..$ :'data.frame': 1 obs. of  2 variables:
##   .. ..$ id  : num 1
##   .. ..$ name: Factor w/ 1 level "John": 1
##   ..$ :'data.frame': 1 obs. of  2 variables:
##   .. ..$ id  : num 1
##   .. ..$ name: Factor w/ 1 level "John": 1
##  $ car   :List of 3
##   ..$ :'data.frame': 1 obs. of  2 variables:
##   .. ..$ id : num 1
##   .. ..$ car: Factor w/ 1 level "Opel": 1
##   ..$ :'data.frame': 1 obs. of  2 variables:
##   .. ..$ id : num 1
##   .. ..$ car: Factor w/ 1 level "Opel": 1
##   ..$ :'data.frame': 1 obs. of  2 variables:
##   .. ..$ id : num 1
##   .. ..$ car: Factor w/ 1 level "Opel": 1
```

...or combine each into a single data.frame with `map`, a version of `lapply` and `dplyr::bind_rows`, akin to `do.call(rbind, ...)`:

```
listMain %>% transpose() %>% map(dplyr::bind_rows)   # purrr pipes well

## $person
##   id name
## 1  1 John
## 2  1 John
## 3  1 John
## 
## $car
##   id  car
## 1  1 Opel
## 2  1 Opel
## 3  1 Opel
```

If you really want two separate lists, `purrr::map` will automatically subset if you pass it a string or number:

```
map(listMain, 'person')

## [[1]]
##   id name
## 1  1 John
## 
## [[2]]
##   id name
## 1  1 John
## 
## [[3]]
##   id name
## 1  1 John
```

...or use the version with the `*_df` suffix to simplify to a data.frame after subsetting:

```
map_df(listMain, 'person')

##   id name
## 1  1 John
## 2  1 John
## 3  1 John
```